# How to update my database access in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my code

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   byte[] imgbyte = null;
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.txtImageLocation.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
   imgbyte = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

   connection.Open();
   string query = "update [Student] set [StudentID] = @StudentID, [Lastname] = @Lastname, [Firstname] = @Firstname, [Image] = @Image where [NID] = '" +lblNID.Text+ "' "; //NID column is my primary key and auto increment

   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", txtStudentID.Text);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtStudentLN.Text);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtStudentFN.Text);
   command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Image", imgbyte));
}
```

Every time I'm trying to update without changing the picture I got ERROR:Empty path is not legal

When I tried to change picture I got an ERROR of data type mismatch in criteria expression

can somebody help me ? thanks in advance!

Here is the Table
[image]

Comment: can u please also share the detail about table structure with column types

Comment: At which line exactly does this error appear ?

Comment: You have used parameters of all update columns, why not used for where clause too? What is the  data type of Image Column? At which line of code you are getting errors?

Comment: You miss a quote in the begin of `string query = update [Student] set [StudentID] ....` place a quote before `update` -> `"update`

Comment: if you're doing an update and dont want to change the picture, DONT update the picture field!

Comment: I'll join to @BugFinder, trace if image is changed, then update record WITH image field, if image wasn't changed, exclude that field when updating

Comment: omg thanks. but how to fix ERROR of data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: my new code `if (StudentPicture.Image != null) { //code in question } else { connection.Open();
   string query = "update [Student] set [StudentID] = @StudentID, [Lastname] = @Lastname, [Firstname] = @Firstname where [NID] = '" +lblNID.Text+ "' ";

   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", txtStudentID.Text);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtStudentLN.Text);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtStudentFN.Text);}`

Comment: Obviously if `Empty path is not legal` then at this point you've got an empty value. In witch line of code this error appear? One of your textboxes at this moment is empty, i think one of those in parameters...

Comment: Or one of the column of table marked as 'NOT NULL' and when you try to past an empty string as parameter he fire an exception.